# Long running process with Classic ASP and .Net via COM Component

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp-classic, com

I'm currently working with a web site written in classic ASP with the back-end code written in .NET 4.5 called via COM component.

My job today is implement a long running task in a method call in the .NET Code. But this method is called via COM component in a classic asp web site.

The behavior I want to achieve is:

- User enter the web page (classic asp)
- User make same actions that trigger the long running task (.net code via com component)
- The page returns to the user regardless of the completion of the task

I'm struggling to find any documentation about the behavior of IIS regarding the execution of .NET code via COM Component inside a classic asp web site.

Information about thread manipulation, AppDomain recycling, etc.

Anyone has same experience with this scenario? Is really difficult to find documentation about this kind of "integration". Any suggestions or any articles to read about this problem (or something related to it) will be really good.

Comment: Rodrigo what you're trying to reach is using a asynchronous call in com+, am I right? You can use queued components, this link can be useful to you:
http://www.codemag.com/Article/0003021.

Let me know if it helped.